# Use Hash Values like an Interval

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have this code:

```
@counter = 719    

@period_hash = {
  :sunset => 360,
  :day    => 720,
  :dawn   => 1200,
}

@period = :nothing

def init_period
  periods = @period_hash.keys
  @period_hash.each_with_index do |(__, number), index|
    if @counter < number
      @period = periods[index - 1]
      break
    end
  end
  if @period == :nothing
    @period = periods[-1]
  end
end

init_period
p @period
```

I have a @counter which will have values between 0 and 1440.
Then I have a hash with variable content. The content will always be symbol => integer
The integer value will also be a number between 0 and 1440 and all numbers are unique in 
the hash. The hash will be sorted, so the lowest number will be first and highest number 
will be last.

Then I have a method(init_period) which will return the key corresponding to the @counter variable.
These are the intervals for the @counter and the returned symbol:

```
0    ..  359  =>   :dawn
360  ..  719  =>   :sunset
720  ..  1199 =>   :day
1200 ..  1440 =>   :dawn
```

It all works, but Im wondering if there are other and better ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve converting your hash to different structure with the following code. It is not very clear, as you are using information outside from `@period_hash` (like global range boundaries and the fact that last value must be reused).

```
hash = @period_hash.
  keys.
  unshift(@period_hash.keys.last).   # reuse last key from hash
  zip(                               # zip keys with ranges
    [0, *@period_hash.values, 1440]. # add 0 and 1440 as boundaries
    each_cons(2)                     # convert array to consecutive pairs enum
  ).each_with_object({}) {|(key, (from, to)), hash|
    hash[from...to] = key            # build actual hash
  }
```

On this structure you can call code that will detect your period:

```
hash.detect {|a,b| a.include?(719) }
```

You end up with really unreadable code. If your periods are not going to change often you could go for very readable code:

```
def init_period(counter)
  case counter
  when 0...360     then :dawn
  when 360...720   then :sunset
  when 720...1200  then :day
  when 1200...1440 then :dawn
  end
end
```

This way period boundaries are not taken from external structure, but code is obvious and clear.

Comment: Thanks, my first solution was with cases, but then I realised, that i write a script to use for others (also some people with no programming knowledge) and I wanted to make it more dynamic. The user of my script can configure the hash and add as many items as he like, as long they follow the rules. It would be easier to add something to the hash, eg, :night => 1300, then to add a new "when" to the case statement somewhere below in the code.

Comment: *On the other hand ranges can be used in case statement. What structure should be used highly depends on actual use case.* (from samuil's comment, lol). Your answer using ranges and `case` statement is totally useless because the OP clearly states that the hash has "variable content". You cannot change a value that is hard coded in a case statement. I shall return your words to you: **What structure should be used highly depends on actual use case**. And the first part of your answer works, but is ugly.